# Showing which dynamic libraries a program loads?

Tags: linux

If I have a program named `program`, is there a way to know which dynamic libraries it loads and uses?

It's a simple question. I can elaborate more if needed, but I'll keep the question simple based on Tomas's suggestion.

Comment: Could downvoter please explain? I understand it's not a very complex problem, but if that upsets you... sorry.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but maybe your question sounds little confusing. The 1st paragraph is there only for confusion, the question started to be clear when I read the 2nd. Maybe just delete the 1st and it will be fine :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can obtain a list of shared libraries that program is linked against with:

```
ldd `which program`
```

Comment: Backticks are obsolete and should no longer be used. This is because you may confuse them with '' or even with ´´ which both have different meaning. The better way is to do it like this: ldd $(which program)

Comment: I like and prefer the backticks. They are nicer to look at and faster to type. If `, ", ', and ´ (the last one is not even ascii) are not visually distinct in a font, then that font is to blame. man bash(1) mentions this style of command substitution as old, but says nothing about obsolete. Is that your personal opinion?